# email confirmation with php and wampserver

Tags: php

I wanted to know if it was possible to test the sending of the confirmation email for a registration with this code :

```
$cle = md5(microtime(TRUE)*100000);

// Insertion de la clé dans la base de données (à adapter en INSERT si besoin)
      $stmt = $bdd->prepare("UPDATE personnes SET cle=:cle WHERE Pseudo = :pseudo");
      $stmt->bindParam(':cle', $cle);
      $stmt->bindParam(':pseudo', $pseudo);
      $stmt->execute();


// Préparation du mail contenant le lien d'activation
      $destinataire = $email;
      $sujet = "Activer votre compte" ;
      $entete = "From: inscription@votresite.com" ;

// Le lien d'activation est composé du login(log) et de la clé(cle)
// penser a changer l adresse du site lorsque celuici sera en ligne
      $message = 'Bienvenue sur blablabla,

      Pour activer votre compte, veuillez cliquer sur le lien ci dessous
      ou copier/coller dans votre navigateur internet.

      http://votresite.com/activation.php?log='.urlencode($pseudo).'&cle='.urlencode($cle).'


      ---------------
      Ceci est un mail automatique, Merci de ne pas y répondre.';


      mail($destinataire, $sujet, $message, $entete) ; // Envoi du mail
```

when you work locally or does it absolutely have its online site

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, install [sendmail](http://glob.com.au/sendmail/) (tutorial on how to install is on their website) to be able to send e-mail from localhost

After this, you can check if mail was sent with simple "if" statement

```
if(mail($destinataire, $sujet, $message, $entete))
{
  //sent
}else{
  //not sent
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On windows, You can try with [Test Mail Server Tool](http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/)